# postrges INSERT RULE instead of UPDATE

Tags: python, database, postgresql, freebsd

I have a simple table consists of three columns; a bigint, a boolean and a text. something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_seq;
CREATE TABLE foo (
    i_foo     BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('foo_seq'),
    isok      BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    who       CHARACTER VARYING(32) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (i_foo);
CREATE RULE foo_insert AS ON INSERT TO foo DO (
    DELETE FROM foo
        WHERE ((foo.i_foo < NEW.i_foo) AND (NEW.who = foo.who))
);
```

It is pretty close to update. I expect after any insertion, the table always has one row and just i_foo increase.

When I insert new item manually, it works fine, it removes the last item and insert the new one. In other words, just i_foo increase by one.

But the same command doest not work the same in python script. All the entities, include the new one, will be removed. and table will be empty after any insertion.

```
INSERT INTO foo (isok, who) VALUES (True, 'someone');

class adoerclass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            isGood = True
            try:
                lock.acquire()
                self.db.execute("INSERT INTO foo (isok, who) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s)", [isGood, 'someone'])
                self.db.commit()
                lock.release()
            except:
                lock.release()
                print("exception!")
                time.sleep(RETRY_TIME)
                lock.release()
```

I am confused.

Comment: Show us the relevant part of your Python code.

Comment: The question was edited. if this part is not enough, I can write more. and table does not have just two columns, I simplified it.

Comment: weird. What if you try to get nextval sequence in Python and insert both columns in Python, not relying on DEFAULT clause?

Comment: I have also checked that
ival = self.db.execute(SELECT nextval('foo_seq')).fetchone()[0]
self.db.execute("INSERT INTO foo (ival, isok) VALUES (%s, %s)", [ival, isGood])
The results were the same. I may insert more part of the code and table. It has five columns and rule may check the contents of other columns. But, the points is 'INSERT' query which I have used the same. TRIGGER might be an alternative I think.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I wrote a trigger for that. It works fine

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_seq;
CREATE TABLE foo (
    i_foo     BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('foo_seq'),
    isok      BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    who       CHARACTER VARYING(32) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (i_foo);
CREATE FUNCTION foo_insert_before() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM foo WHERE (( NEW.i_foo > foo.i_foo ) AND (NEW.who = foo.who));
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_insert BEFORE INSERT ON foo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_insert_before();
```